# Methods in finding invariant subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving, invariant-subspace

Suppose I have a linear transformation $f: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^n}$ and i want to find all the invariant subspaces under $f$. What is a good approach?

I know that $\mathbb{R^n}, \{0_n\}$ are the trivial subspaces and that for $dim1$ I work with eigenvectors.But, i have $2$ questions.

1. For $ dim1$, are the eigenspaces the only invariant subspaces? If not, what do I do to find others?
2. What about higher dimensions? What do I do there?

Thank you.

Comment: This question is completely answered by what is called the rational canonical form of $f$, generalizing Jordan normal form. There are, roughly speaking, two kinds of invariant subspaces other than eigenspaces. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form#A_rational_normal_form_generalizing_the_Jordan_normal_form for details.

Comment: You can probably answer your first question yourself if you consider what linearity of $f$ implies about its behavior on a one-dimensional invariant space.